# HTML 5 input type Time not working on android

Tags: android, html, typescript

I am working on a hybrid mobile application. Using ionic 2 framework. HTML5 input type time showing unusual behavior. When i am setting 12 hour format value to input tag time is continuously displayed in 24 hour format. Working fine on google chrome browser and IOS Devices. But not working on Android Devices.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

> One thing to note is that the displayed time format may differ from the actual value — the displayed time format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's operating system, whereas the date value is always formatted hh:mm. When the above value submitted to the server, for example, some browsers display it as 13:30, some display it as 1.30 PM, but the submitted value will always look like appt-time=13%3A30.